# How to call Static method in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have third party DLL(written in c#)

That has a class called `DBConnection` and static method called `Connect`
When I call that method from my C# console application like below it will work fine.

```
DataPackage.Db.DBConnection.Connect()
```

Next I tried to do the same thing using powershell.

```
[DataPackage.Db.DBConnection]::Connect()
```

But that gives me error

```
Exception calling "Connect" with "0" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

What is the reason for this and how to fix this??

Comment: It may be helpful to tell us what the third party library is and point us to any documentation on the class/method.

Comment: the error above points to the fact that connect() needs to be called from an instance of the class, so a simple x= new-object [DataPackage.Db.DBConnection] or similar followed by x.connect() will resolve this. :)

Answer (score 43):

I hate to drop an answer without a reference beyond personal experience, but I have never found an explanation for this behavior, so sorry this is not more informative.

When calling a parameterless method leave off the parens.  So for your example do:

```
[DataPackage.Db.DBConnection]::Connect
```

instead of ...Connect()

Answer (score 2):

That's not a problem with PowerShell per se because your method call is indeed correct. Apparently the method itself tries to dereference `null` somewhere. Maybe other methods have to be called first, or maybe a static property set somewhere.

Comment: Is there any way to fix this or determine what is the actual cause.?

Comment: Looking in the code, I guess, i.e. disassembling it. I'm still trying ti think of a way why this won't be triggered in C#, apparently